# jQuery Date/Time picker customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-timepicker

All previous dates should be greyed out. [Done using `'minDate: '0''`] 
All dates that the salon is closed on should be greyed out: I have tried using `beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends` but here the case is Monday and Sunday. Kindly advice how can i fix that.

When the user selects the Day, Time will correspond to the hours of operation. i.e if the user selects Tuesday the hours will show up from 9 - 6 but if the user selects the Friday the times will show from 9 -9.

Also if the time has already passed i.e if the time is 12pm, the timings from 9 - 10, 10 - 11, 11 - 12 will be greyed out in the dropdown for that day but will be available if the user selects another day.

Kindly answer as much as you can.

Comment: that's not possible (at least out-of-the-box). AFAIK

Comment: That's a lovely list of requirements, but what's your question?